# How to Store Array name in array in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, function

Here is my problem:-

I have two string array which contains array name(integer) as a string. 
Now I need to compare each integer array to remaining arrays.

Lets Suppose I have array

```
    int[] data;
    data1 = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    data2 = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    data3 = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    data4 = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    data5 = new int[] {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};

   /*Now divide the above data into two parts like data1 and data2 is in one side and other content is other side and each array will compare with other set of arrays. i.e. array data1 will compare with array data3, data4, data5. and same for data2 array */

    String [] str= new String[2];
    String [] str1= new String[3];

    str[0]="data";  //Name Of the first array.
    str[1]="data2"; //This is also other array name

     str1[0]="data3";
     str1[1]="data4";
     str1[2]="data5";
    //Now I need to call a function passing array name as the parameter.

   for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
   {
     for(int j=0;j<str1.length();j++)
      {
        compare(str[i],str1[j]);   //this is error part   


    //and the function definition is 
    public void compare(int[] x1, int[] x2)
    {//compare code
    }
```

But getting error:-
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int[]

Comment: use a Map<String, int[]>.

Comment: I think you intend to do `compare(data)` instead of `compare(str[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass `String` to the method which accepts `int[]`.
I see two ways here:

1. create separate class for storing name of the array, array itself and pass the object of that class to the method compare.
2. use `Map<String, Integer[]>` to store "name" -> `int[]`

import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

```
public class Main {

    public static final String NAME_1 = "data";
    public static final String NAME_2 = "data2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, int[]> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(NAME_1, new int[]{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 71, 80, 90, 91});
        data.put(NAME_2, new int[]{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 71, 80, 90, 91});
        // etc...
        compare(data.get(NAME_1));
    }

    public static void compare(int[] x1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(x1[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey can you help in programming using map method.

Comment: @Ankur_009 I've updated my answer

Comment: after inserting the data. I need to store the array name or  map into the array... then show the content..

Comment: I provided the solution for your question. If you want to solve your particular problem having it coded then submit bounty program otherwise accept the answer, please.

Comment: I updated my question. The answer provided is not what I am asking. Please.. @Andy.